# Make a binding on ElementName to change when trigered

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm probably missing something because what I do is suposed to work I think. I'm trying to bind the ElementName of a value to change when trigered.

here's the code (it is in the style):

```
<ContentPresenter>
  <ContentPresenter.Style>
    <Style>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tick}" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName={Binding FieldNameFocus}}"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ContentPresenter.Style>
</ContentPresenter>
```

And get this error:

```
Error   2   A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'ElementName' property of type 'Binding'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.   C:\Users\xavier\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Test_Validation\Test_Validation\MainWindow.xaml   1   2   Test_Validation
```

Maybe I'm not in the right path though... I just want to have focusedElement to change according to `FieldNameFocus` when `Tick` becomes True. (Both are in my dataContext)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your binding should look like this: `Value="{Binding ElementName=YourElementName, Path=PropertyOfTheElement}"`

Example binding by ElementName:

`<TextBox Name="tbx1" Text="TextBox"/>`

`<TextBox  Name="tbx2" Text="{Binding ElementName=tbx1, Path=Text}"/>`

Comment: Is "YourElementName" suposed to be my datacontext..? please explain more

Comment: Updated my answer. This is how you bind by ElementName.

Comment: No it doesn't help me much.. FieldNameFocus is a property in my datacontext which contains the name of a field (and will change, that is why it is in my dataContext)

Answer (score 0):

Hello the error is pretty clear, you cannot use Binding on with ElementName. When using ElementName you should provide the name of a control present in your xaml File as the previous post showed. As your trigger is bind to a boolean value you might want to replace `"ElementName={Binding FieldNameFocus}"` by 
`"ElementName=controlNameOnWhichYouWantToSetFocus"`.

Eg `<Textbox x:Name="ControlIWantFocusOnWhenTickIstrue">` then in your trigger

```
<Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName="ControlIWantFocusOnWhenTickIstrue"/>
```